# .bib file not printing all references at end in reference section

Tags: bibtex

I am trying the ACM conference template ... the references are printing but 2 references didn't get printed? Note: I cited these references in in text citation. What can be the reason for this ??

First on Google Scholar I am researching the paper. Then open ref style-->click on bibTex-->
then copying this

```
    @article{maskin1999nash,
    title={Nash equilibrium and welfare optimality},
    author={Maskin, Eric},
    journal={The Review of Economic Studies},
    volume={66},
    number={1},
    pages={23--38},
    year={1999},
    publisher={Wiley-Blackwell} }
```

and pasted in my .bib file (sample-bibliography.bib). Then in the main file I am using `\bibliography{sample-bibliography}` to print a reference in the reference section

Comment: check the blg-file for messages.

Comment: have you run latex, then bibtex to generate the bibliography then latex again to include it? since adding the extra entry to the bib file?

Comment: Why is this tagged biblatex if you're actually using standard bibtex?

Comment: Do you have any cite commands. If you want them all to print you need a `\cite{*}` command.